# Redis The client is closed

Tags: javascript, caching, redis

Am trying to learn redis, am fetching github repo data, and then i want to cache it with redis. but i'm getting error why trying to use redis:

redis-and-fetch/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:409
return Promise.reject(new errors_1.ClientClosedError());

ClientClosedError: The client is closed

this is my code

```
import express from "express";
import Redis from "redis";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const REDIS_PORT = process.env.REDIS_PORT || "6379";

const client = Redis.createClient(REDIS_PORT);

const app = express();

// Set response
function setResponse(username, repos) {
  return `<h2>${username} has ${repos} Github repos</h2>`;
}

// Make request to Github for data
async function getRepos(req, res, next) {
  try {
    console.log("Fetching Data...");

    const { username } = req.params;

    const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`);

    const data = await response.json();

    const repos = data.public_repos;

    // Set data to Redis
    // await client.connect();
    client.setEx(username, 3600, repos);

    res.send(setResponse(username, repos));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500);
  }
}

app.get("/repos/:username", getRepos);

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

how can i fix this error?

Comment: Why did you comment out the call to `client.connect()`?

Comment: If i uncomment connect, Am getting this error: /redis-and-fetch/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/RESP2/encoder.js:17
            throw new TypeError('Invalid argument type');
                  ^

TypeError: Invalid argument type

Comment: Is your Redis server running on localhost port 6379? Also, just passing a port number to `createClient()` doesn't actually do anything, see [the fine manual](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/HEAD/docs/client-configuration.md).

Comment: i have strange problem my redis status is      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-07-24 14:21:23 +04; 13min ago
    Process: 38470 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
but i can enter redis-cli on 6379 port, why redis status is failed ?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a gander at the [README](https://github.com/redis/node-redis) for Node Redis, you will find this bit of sample code:

```js
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const client = createClient();

client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

await client.connect();

await client.set('key', 'value');
const value = await client.get('key');
```

This works find if you want to connect to Redis running locally and on the default port. If you want to connect to somewhere else, the [client configuration guide](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/HEAD/docs/client-configuration.md) shows you how. A couple of common ways are shown below:

```js
/* the host, port, and password probably from process.env or something */
const host = 'awesome.redis.server'
const port = 6380

/* create a client using host and port */
const client = createClient({ socket : { host, port } })

/* create a client with a Redis URL */
const url = `redis://${host}:${port}`
const client = createClient({ url })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with redis when using version 4.2.0 there are two changes required in order for the error to be solved.

1. Firstly client.connect is no longer done automatically so it has to done manually.
2. Secondly I advise to use client.set in the format below.

```html
import express from "express";
import Redis from "redis";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const REDIS_PORT = process.env.REDIS_PORT || "6379";

const {createClient} = redis;
const client  = createClient();
client.connect();

const app = express();
app.use(express.json())   


// Set response
function setResponse(username, repos) {
  return `<h2>${username} has ${repos} Github repos</h2>`;
}

// Make request to Github for data
async function getRepos(req, res, next) {
  try {
    console.log("Fetching Data...");

    const { username } = req.params;

    const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`);

    const data = await response.json();

    const repos = data.public_repos;


    //updated set method for v4
     await client.set(username, repos, {
            EX: 10,
            NX: true
      });
    res.send(setResponse(username, repos));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500);
  }
}

app.get("/repos/:username", getRepos);

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

to get the cached data run
const data = await client.get(username);